# to be present in any field or sphere. context

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, collocations

Variety is present also in the fild of/ at / in sphere of touching experiences,  that are rough, hard, smooth and soft, and these combinations give an extra dimension to the collection.

What use better? in the field or sphere or something different?

Comment: Quite aside from what I wrote in my answer, below, I have a hunch that the word "texture" would be useful to you.  Are we talking about photography? See http://texture.livejournal.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for **aspect**.  And I think rather than *touching*, you mean **tactile** (the adjective which means "of the sense of touch").

Thus:

> Variety is present also in the aspect of tactile experiences, that are rough, hard, smooth, and soft, and these combinations give an extra dimension to the collection.

Which still has an error: you need a **which** instead of *that*:

> Variety is present also in the aspect of tactile experiences, which are rough, hard, smooth, and soft, and these combinations give an extra dimension to the collection.